# How can I add the arrow of the maximum and minimum value in iOS-charts?

Tags: ios-charts

I want to show the arrow of the maximum and minimum value just like the picture below.

Does anyone have ideas about how to achieve it using iOS-Charts? Thanks a lot.

[image: Chart description]

Comment: So what have you tried so far? :)

Comment: No thing, I heard that the Android version has the property to show the arrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your own custom renderer for `CandleStickChartView`. 
Fortunately, in your case you need overwrite only one method.

So, inherit class from `CandleStickChartRenderer` and override method `drawValues(context: CGContext)`. You can just copy/paste most of the code from parent's method and make only necessary changes.

```swift
class MyCandleStickChartRenderer: CandleStickChartRenderer {

    internal var _xBounds = XBounds()

    var minValue: Double
    var maxValue: Double

    init (view: CandleStickChartView, minValue: Double, maxValue: Double) {
        self.minValue = minValue
        self.maxValue = maxValue

        super.init(dataProvider: view, animator: view.chartAnimator, viewPortHandler: view.viewPortHandler)
    }

    override func drawValues(context: CGContext)
    {
        // ... I remove some code that was not changed ...

            for j in stride(from: _xBounds.min, through: _xBounds.range + _xBounds.min, by: 1)
            {
                guard let e = dataSet.entryForIndex(j) as? CandleChartDataEntry else { break }

                // need to show only min and max values
                guard e.high == maxValue || e.low == minValue else { continue }

                pt.x = CGFloat(e.x)
                if e.high == maxValue {
                    pt.y = CGFloat(e.high * phaseY)
                } else if e.low == minValue {
                    pt.y = CGFloat(e.low * phaseY)
                }
                pt = pt.applying(valueToPixelMatrix)

                // ... I remove some code that was not changed ...   

                if dataSet.isDrawValuesEnabled
                {
                    var textValue: String?
                    var align: NSTextAlignment = .center

                    // customize position for min/max value 
                    if e.high == maxValue {
                        pt.y -= yOffset
                        textValue = "←  " + String(maxValue)
                        align = .left
                    } else if e.low == minValue {
                        pt.y += yOffset / 5
                        textValue = String(minValue) + "  →"
                        align = .right
                    }

                    if let textValue = textValue {
                        ChartUtils.drawText(
                            context: context,
                            text: textValue,
                            point: CGPoint(
                                x: pt.x,
                                y: pt.y ),
                            align: align,
                            attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: valueFont, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: dataSet.valueTextColorAt(j)])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also you need to create instance of your renderer and set it as property in your chart view.

```swift
myCandleStickChartView.renderer = MyCandleStickChartRenderer(view: candleStickChartView, minValue: 400, maxValue: 1450)
```

And in the end ...

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, you have solved my question perfectly.