# iOS Charts - Display highest and lowest value for CandleStick charts

Tags: ios-charts

I'm trying to create a candlestick chart using [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)

As you guys can notice from my screenshot, the chart only shows the highest and lowest values instead of displaying the values for all the candles. Is there any way I can implement that with the Charts framework?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: This is Android screenshot, and Charts link you've added is for iOS projects. Some of those informations are misleading here.

Comment: Edited screenshot to prevent confusion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add the arrow of the maximum and minimum value in iOS-charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49381948/how-can-i-add-the-arrow-of-the-maximum-and-minimum-value-in-ios-charts)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display only highest and lowest values, you need to implement you own renderer inherited from `CandleStickChartRenderer`. In fact you just need to override one function `drawValues(context: CGContext)`.

I have made some example which contain a hundred lines of code, but in fact my custom code contains about thirty lines.

```swift
class MyCandleStickChartRenderer: CandleStickChartRenderer {

    private var _xBounds = XBounds() // Reusable XBounds object

    private var minValue: Double
    private var maxValue: Double

    // New constructor
    init (view: CandleStickChartView, minValue: Double, maxValue: Double) {
        self.minValue = minValue
        self.maxValue = maxValue

        super.init(dataProvider: view, animator: view.chartAnimator, viewPortHandler: view.viewPortHandler)
    }

    // Override draw function 
    override func drawValues(context: CGContext)
    {
        guard
            let dataProvider = dataProvider,
            let candleData = dataProvider.candleData
            else { return }

        guard isDrawingValuesAllowed(dataProvider: dataProvider) else { return }

        var dataSets = candleData.dataSets

        let phaseY = animator.phaseY

        var pt = CGPoint()

        for i in 0 ..< dataSets.count
        {
            guard let dataSet = dataSets[i] as? IBarLineScatterCandleBubbleChartDataSet
                else { continue }

            let valueFont = dataSet.valueFont
            let trans = dataProvider.getTransformer(forAxis: dataSet.axisDependency)
            let valueToPixelMatrix = trans.valueToPixelMatrix

            _xBounds.set(chart: dataProvider, dataSet: dataSet, animator: animator)

            let lineHeight = valueFont.lineHeight
            let yOffset: CGFloat = lineHeight + 5.0

            for j in stride(from: _xBounds.min, through: _xBounds.range + _xBounds.min, by: 1)
            {
                guard let e = dataSet.entryForIndex(j) as? CandleChartDataEntry else { break }

                guard e.high == maxValue || e.low == minValue else { continue }

                pt.x = CGFloat(e.x)
                if e.high == maxValue {
                    pt.y = CGFloat(e.high * phaseY)
                } else if e.low == minValue {
                    pt.y = CGFloat(e.low * phaseY)
                }
                pt = pt.applying(valueToPixelMatrix)

                if (!viewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(pt.x))
                {
                    break
                }

                if (!viewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(pt.x) || !viewPortHandler.isInBoundsY(pt.y))
                {
                    continue
                }

                if dataSet.isDrawValuesEnabled
                {
                    // In this part we draw min and max values
                    var textValue: String?
                    var align: NSTextAlignment = .center
                    if e.high == maxValue {
                        pt.y -= yOffset
                        textValue = "←  " + String(maxValue)
                        align = .left
                    } else if e.low == minValue {
                        pt.y += yOffset / 5
                        textValue = String(minValue) + "  →"
                        align = .right
                    }

                    if let textValue = textValue {
                        ChartUtils.drawText(
                            context: context,
                            text: textValue,
                            point: CGPoint(
                                x: pt.x,
                                y: pt.y ),
                            align: align,
                            attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: valueFont, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: dataSet.valueTextColorAt(j)])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do not forget use you custom renderer for you chart. ;)

```
myCandleStickChartView.renderer = MyCandleStickChartRenderer(view: myCandleStickChartView, minValue: 400, maxValue: 1450)
```

[image: Chart view]

Comment: I haven't checked the one you linked, but if it's an exact match, this will go one of two ways: either this will be deleted as a link-only answer (if you roll back to revision 2), or it will be deleted as a duplicate answer (and yes, there are actually rules on that too). Either flag the question as a duplicate (if it is), or tailor your answer to the question.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try with your solution.